How do I import sklearn along with numpy and pandas
I have copied this from our university's ipynb notebook, but it's stopping at importing sklearn (which has already been installed with pip). Even if I take out sklearn, it's stopping at pandas.
import numpy as np
import sklearn
import pandas as pd

I expected it to run, which eventually means that I should be able to read the training data with a csv file, but it is not working. What should I do?

Do you have a file named "sklearn.py" in the current directory?

I do not but I have installed sklearn via pip

You need to use pip install scikit-learn, as the way you did it is deprecated. However, the namespace is the same, so don’t change the import sklearn line.
